# É possível tornar o optgroup label selecionável?

Tags: html

É possivel tornar a opção do `optgroup label` selecionável juntamente com o restando das opções do grupo, por exemplo:

```
 <optgroup label="EUA">
<option value="0">NY</option>
<option value="1">LA</option>
```

Só que EUA também teria que ser uma opção selecionável, mas ela ainda tem que ser mostrada como pai dessas duas opções.

Comment: Acredito que isso não seja possível. Você pode tentar estilizar o `select` com CSS pra alcançar um resultado semelhante, mas na resposta aceita [desta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag) do SOen, fica claro pelos comentários que isso não funciona na maioria dos navgadores.

Comment: Eu li exatamente esta pergunta, e fiquei na dúvida, então eu mesmo vou ter que estilizar meu menu de alguma forma.. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Foi interessante sua perguta, mais realmente não a como até o momento.

Comment: Laguma das respostas lhe serviu ou orientou na sua dúvida @MichelHenriq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, pesquisei aqui em uma fonte segura a W3School e realmente isso não é possivel fazer com a tag `<optgroup>`, pois ela é uma opção de agrupamento de `<options>` e não um seletor.

Fonte:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: É, cheguei na mesma conclusão pesquisando ao mesmo tempo e no mesmo lugar que você. :) +1

Comment: O jeito que achei é fazer um combox com select autocomplete do jquery ui, assim eu consigo mascarar um pouco essa deficiência na parte do select.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Talvez você poderia usar o Select2, que é um framework do javascript. =)

Comment: Eu vi esse Select2, mas ele ainda não atende o que eu preciso. O que eu vou fazer é montar um array personalizado, colocando os países com um h3 para diferenciar, e com isso, colocar um autocomplete no select, caso o usuário digite, assim fica mais fácil a interação.
Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Estive dando uma pesquisada, e seguindo um "pista" que encontrei num comentário de uma das respostas da pergunta que postei no comentário  acima (na pergunta), acho que o motivo disso ser impossível apenas com HTML simples é o seguinte:

> [optgroup has no attribute value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892287/4734177)

Ou seja, não é possível porque `optgroup` **não tem um atributo `value`**. Conforme você pode ver [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp), os únicos atributos de `optgroup` são:

> **Attribute   | Value  |   Description**
>
> **disabled** |    disabled | Specifies that an option-group should be disabled
>   **label**  |  text |       Specifies a label for an option-group